# Drupal ui inside module

Tags: 7, javascript

Am i doing wrong to define, jQuery Accordion inside my .module file,
just like this:

```
<?php 
  drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.accordion');
```

Drupal no longer loading jquery itself.

Comment: Drupal loads Jquery by default... Jquery UI Plugins needs to be loaded separately based on requirement as you did above...

Comment: Where you load the library from depends on what you are trying to do. To get the best possible answer you need to provide more information on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you doing that at the top level and not inside a function / hook?

Comment: @MPD, now i am doing it as suggested below and it is running fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add below code in your theme template.php

```
function NAME_OF_THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.accordion');
}
```

Comment: This is also not preferred; `#attached` in a render array should be used if we're being strict about it :)

Comment: @Clive : Interested to know why it's not preferred way to do...

Comment: I'm not 100% (I've only seen this mentioned in issues on d.o and perhaps a question or two here), but I think mostly because of render array caching. Theoretically the preprocess method should have the same effect, but I think they're trying to standardise how css/js/libraries are added to pages by using render arrays. This is certainly more true for Drupal 8, so maybe the ethos is being backported if not the full code

Comment: Looks like this method is working better for the OP, maybe this is the better approach for adding libraries globally

Answer (score 7):

Yes that's wrong, you need to put it inside a hook function.

Which one depends on where you're trying to use it. To add it to a render array, for example a form, you might use

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = array('system', 'ui.accordion');
```

Comment: API page says, This hook_init is not run on cached pages.

To add CSS or JS that should be present on all pages, modules should not implement this hook, but declare these files in their .info file.

Comment: Fair enough @AnilSagar, though I've never had a problem using that method with caching enabled (and the docs have been wrong before). I've updated the answer with the globally accepted solution

Comment: liked the first answer, now .. i still don't know what excatly to put in my module file. :(

Comment: Sorry @Roland, Anil was right to bring that up as the docs do explicitly say not to do that. `hook_page_alter()` might be appropriate: `function MYMODULE_page_alter(&$page) { $page['#attached']['library'][] = array('system', 'ui.accordion'); }`. It'll need a cache clear to work

Comment: a question in direct correlation with this topic.
do i have to uninstall / install the module with every try, or is it enought to flush the cache ?

Comment: Flush the cache is enough...

Comment: @Roland Any time you add a new hook or change the module .info file (and maybe in a couple of other situations) you need to flush the caches for the changes to get picked up. You only need to uninstall and reinstall if you change your module's db schema (but in that case you can use an update hook instead). So flushing caches will do the trick for most things

Comment: maybe there is a typo inside but the page_alter is not working? preprocess_page is working.

Comment: I didn't try it but it "should" work since the `$page` array gets run through `drupal_render()`, and that invokes the `#attached` functionality. In theory at least. If the preprocess method works, go with that one - it'll have the same effect and shouldn't break caching. Interesting that it doesn't work with the page alter hook though

Comment: ok thx to both of you :)